# Microservices in SF: C# can't find type

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I'm implementing a number of micrososervices with C# and Service Fabric. All has gone well until this error which seems to be a C# error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IProductCatalogService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ECommerce.API   C:\dev\ECommerce\ECommerce.API\Controllers\ProductsController.cs    14  Active
```

IProductCatalogService is the project ECommerce.ProductCatalog.Model which I have set a project dependency to and I am referencing with a using statement:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ECommerce.API.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ECommerce.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IProductCatalogService _catalogService;
```

Here it is ECommerce.ProductCatalog.Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting;

namespace ECommerce.ProductCatalog.Model
{
    public interface IProductCatalogService : IService
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetAllProducts();
        Task AddProduct(Product product);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you have imported Ecommerce.api.model but error says that file is in Ecommerce.api. can you please ensure your file is im model folder and not outside model folder? It will be helpful if you share folder structure and file  location

Comment: Wrong `using` statement? from your description it sounds like you want `using ECommerce.ProductCatalog.Model;`.

Comment: You're right Pep! But it won't let me add the using statement even though I have referenced the project ECommerce.ProductCatalog.Model in the project dependencies

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots above, it looks like you're missing out on referencing to the right project. You want to use **using Ecommerce.Productcatalog.Model** after you add the reference of Ecommerce.Productcatalog.Model  in UI Project.

And from your comments it looks like you have done that and yet you're not able to add that reference. In that case, can you share the screenshot of what it says when you try adding that using statement and also share the project/folder structure if possible, so we can take a look it further.